# PostgreSQL's psql.exe doesn't validate password

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I have an issue with my PostgreSQL - the `psql.exe` ignores anything I write as password for it.

What I do so far:

I run a simple (Powershell) script to start Postgre:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin\pg_ctl.exe" `
  'start -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\pg95"''
```

With that running, I can now access the database with something like this:

```
& "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin\psql.exe" `
  --dbname=$databaseName --host=$dbHost --username=$userName -c $sqlString
```

But most unfourtunately the terminal **does not prompt me for a password**!

This is odd, since `psql.exe --help` gives the line:

```
..
-W, --password: force password prompt (should happen automatically)
```

But it does not.
When I try applying `-W` it prompts me, but ignores what I write, and lets me access the database.

So the solution could be, that `%appdata%\Postgresql\pgpass.conf` set the password, but it's empty.
Another solution is the environmental variable `PGPASSWORD` is set, but I can't see it set anywhere. I tried `Get-ChildItem Env:` in Powershell, and `set` in cmd, but neither have it set.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Learn more about [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortest, but most helpful answer I've ever seen, @abelisto.

My `pg_hba.conf`, located under `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\pg95\` said:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# IPv4 local & remote connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

[From Abelisto's link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) `trust` is defined as:

> Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password or any other authentication.

Switching them to `md5` gave a better result:

> Require the client to supply a double-MD5-hashed password for authentication.

Comment: Your confusion is not unjustified. People find it weird that you can create a user `WITH PASSWORD` and they aren't required to use a password to log in, or that you can create a user `WITHOUT PASSWORD` then get prompted for a password (when you'd expect silent login). It makes sense when you realise that the password is only used if `password` or `md5` auth methods are used in `pg_hba.conf`, so it controls *what* the password is *if* one is needed, not *whether* one is needed. Not super user friendly though.